# Android TextView Timer

Tags: java, android, timer, textview

For my Android application there is a timer that measures how much time has passed. Ever 100 milliseconds I update my TextView with some text like "Score: 10 Time: 100.10 seconds". But, I find the TextView only updates the first few times. The application is still very responsive, but the label will not update. I tried to call .invalidate(), but it still does not work. I don't know if there is some way to fix this, or a better widget to use.

Here is a example of my code:

```
float seconds;
java.util.Timer gametimer;
void updatecount() { TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.topscore);
t.setText("Score: 10 - Time: "+seconds+" seconds");
t.postInvalidate();
}
public void onCreate(Bundle sis) {
... Load the UI, etc...
  gametimer.schedule(new TimerTask() { public void run() {
     seconds+=0.1; updatecount();
} }, 100, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The general solution is to use android.os.Handler instead which runs in the UI thread.  It only does one-shot callbacks, so you have to trigger it again every time your callback is called.  But it is easy enough to use.  A blog post on this topic was written a couple of years ago:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2007/11/stitch-in-time.html

Comment: Thank you for this link. The code on that page worked perfectly with my TextView-based timer.

Answer (score 2):

What I think is happening is you're falling off the UI thread.  There is a single "looper" thread which handles all screen updates.  If you attempt to call "invalidate()" and you're not on this thread nothing will happen.

Try using "postInvalidate()" on your view instead.  It'll let you update a view when you're not in the current UI thread.

More info [here](http://code.google.com/android/reference/android/view/View.html#postInvalidate())

Comment: It still does not work - it updates the first time so I know its working but does not update after that. Thanks anyway, Isaac.

Answer (score 1):

Use Below code to set time on TextView

```
public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
        public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
            super(startTime, interval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

            ExamActivity.this.submitresult();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            long millis = millisUntilFinished;

            int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000) % 60;
            int minutes = (int) ((millis / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
            int hours = (int) ((millis / (1000 * 60`enter code here` * 60)) % 24);

            String ms = String
                    .format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
            txtimedisplay.setText(ms);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way to change text each second; this is `ValueAnimator`. Here is my solution:

```
  long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  ValueAnimator animator = new ValueAnimator();
            animator.setObjectValues(0, 1000);
            animator.setDuration(1000);
            animator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
            animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    String text = TimeFormatUtils.formatTime(startTime - currentTime);
                   yourTextView.setText(text);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    String text = TimeFormatUtils.formatTime(startTime - currentTime);
                    yourTextView.setText(text);
                }
            });
            animator.start();
```